# Visual studio 2022: Running low priority background processes never completing

Tags: angular, visual-studio, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I have been deep diving for a resolution to the issue "Running low priority background processes" an have come up short. This seemed to be a problem many years ago and the only solution was to install the updated version of VS. I am running the current version. My project is Angular(current) and .net 6 web api. Does anyone know how to resolve this or even how to check which processes are running so I can see what is getting hung? If I close studio down and open it, it will complete until I make a change to a file or open a file. Then the queue jumps to 20. This started happening yesterday I made a change to the tsconfig file which I rolled back hoping it would solve the issue.

tsconfig.json

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any problematic side effects of this behavior? Or why do you care?

Comment: @PMF yes I maybe wrong but angular projects arent loading or linting.

Comment: @PMF I have the same issue, but on a non-angular project, the side effect is that VS blocks to run tests, from Test Explorer, apparently it never finishes building the project.

Comment: I'm not sure this is related. I sometimes see the background processes running all the time, but VS works just fine.